# Sign-in only to selected Stack Exchange communities and stay signed out from others

Tags: support, login

I would like to keep signed in only to selected Stack Exchange communities and stay signed out from others.

But whenever I log into one community, I'm immediately signed in all others communities.

Comment: May I ask why? What's the harm in being logged in everywhere? All sites you already are a member of or would join would be linked up to the same account anyway.

Comment: Well, it's complicated story, though it's related to communities where I wouldn't like to be associated anymore.

Comment: If you delete your profiles on those communities, there will be no remaining association. And if you'd rather not do that for some reason, there's the ability to "hide" communities from your profile (although it's more of a convenience feature rather than a true privacy measure). Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, deleting is too harsh, truly speaking I thought about that. My mood was such that I'd be rather happy to delete my account than to be associated with [ru.stackoverflow.com](http://ru.stackoverflow.com). In the end I changed my mind...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this through Stack Exchange (that I know of).

However, there is a kinda hacky way to do this: you can block cookies for the site. If you're using Chrome, you can do that like this:

1. Click on the paper or the lock icon just to the left of the URL
2. Click on "### from this site" underneath "cookies"
3. Scroll through the list and find the entry that is the domain for the site you want to block (e.g. for Aviation.SE you would click on <kbd>aviation.stackexchange.com</kbd>)
4. Click <kbd>Block</kbd>

You're done!

If you want to unblock the site, follow steps 1 and 2 above, click on the "blocked" tab, find the site, click <kbd>Allow</kbd>. Alternatively, you can click on the cookie with the red "x" that is just to the right of the URL, then select "Always allow...", and click <kbd>Done</kbd>.